# Major mode to colour fragments such as tables

Tags: faces, major-mode

I would like to define a major mode for some class of documents, a few faces, and fontification rules that find fragments users would want colored and apply those faces.  The user will be able to customize the faces to their liking.

As a use case, users could colour cells in a table as they wish.  When they load the file again, the colours would persist.

How would a basic major-mode with specific faces that would colour cells in a table look like?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have included the question in the last sentence.